# Why Logic in __destruct

Tags: php, design-patterns

I found the following code. Is this a specific pattern or what could be the reason to structure code like that - or is it just bogus?

```
class ExportCSV extends Export
{
    // some private and public vars

    public function __construct($arg)
    {
    // [...]
        new CustomerReport($this);
    }

    public function procCallback($proc)
    {
        switch($proc){
            case "customer":
                new InvoiceReport($this);
                break;
            case "invoice":
                new PrepaymentReport($this);
                break;
            case "prepayment":
                new RefundReport($this);
                break;
            case "refund":
                $this->sendMail();
                break;
        }
    }
}

class CustomerReport extends Foobar
{
    private $inst;
    public function __construct($inst)
    {
        $this->inst = $inst;
        $this->exportCustomers($inst->from, $inst->to);
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->inst->procCallback("customer");
    }
}
```

Comment: what's `InvoiceReport` contain?

Answer (score 2):

As raina77ow said, is an implementation of a pattern. Besides, you must to consider what do you want to do once the object is destroyed in you application life cycle. Let's consider the following example (please, it is just an example!)

Let's suppose you are trying to implement an MVC pattern and you are the guy who should make the "View part". So what do you need? you need grab all the variables generated in the request and once they're ready to be used in the response (thru the controllers and Models) they should be rendered into the views. One approach (among others, of course) is the implementation of this pattern (Observer) through the magic method __destruct(). For example something like this:

```
// your code here
public function __destruct() {
    $this->grabAllTheVarsAndRenderThem();
    // or you can include the views file
    extract($this->viewParams);
    include_once('my_file_view.php');
}
```

This is just an example, and btw, is very verbosed (*as you can see in the method name*). But the idea behind the example is, *bind some behavior before the object is destroyed*.

Of course there are a lot of situations where you can -and you should- implement this pattern, this is just an example to explain the sense to use this magic method.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call the shown code 'Logic' in destructor: it's actually an implementation of [Observer](http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/php-design-patterns-observer-pattern.html) pattern.

I assume here it works like that: first, when a `CustomerReport` object is created, its constructor will register some observing objects (probably with `$this->exportCustomers` method, which body is not shown here for some reasons) in its `$inst` field. Then these observing objects will be notified each time this object's state is changed. And, of course, destruction of this object can be viewed as changing of its state too. )

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the original developer of this part of the code doesn't trust the users (that could be the same person too (-: ) of these libraries and want to make sure that every `CustomerReport` created will do call the collaborator objects (they could be releasing some lock or other critical resource).